# regexp_replace with negative lookahead to clean up email addresses

Tags: regex, postgresql, regex-lookarounds

In postgres I'm using **regexp_replace** to clean up some yahoo email addresses.

```
SELECT regexp_replace(domain,'yahoo\.co[^\.].*','yahoo.com')  FROM table
```

Unfortunately, this expression matches this type **yahoo.com.tw** that I'd like to **NOT MATCH**. I'd like the regex to:

**NOT MATCH**:

```
yahoo.es
yahoo.co.jp
yahoo.com.tw
```

**MATCH**:

```
yahoo.com,
yahoo.com.
yahoo.com'
```

I've been at this for several hours and have looked at several links in stack like this:
[Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

They have helped me write a negative lookahead but can't seem to combine it with the **yahoo** portion

**NEGATIVE LOOKAHEAD**

```
     ^(?!.*(\.com?\.|\.[a-z]{2})).*$
```

Here is the  [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Ko0Pyf/7) data and formula.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Should `yahoo.es'` match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern matches everything directly below your yahoo REPLACE section and non of the good cases above:

```
^yahoo\.com?(?:(?!\.[a-z]{2}).)*(?:.com?)?$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jCg4hx/1)

The other cases below, like yahool.com, can be added as optional matches, like this:

```
^yahoo\.com?(?:(?!\.[a-z]{2}).)*(?:.com?)?$|^yahoo$|^yahool\.com|^yahooo\.com|^yahoo\.net|^yahoocom$
```

etc. However, some can be grouped easily together.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks.  What does the 2nd Non capturing group do ? ie this one : `(?:.com?)?$`

Comment: Legit question. It handles the special case: yahoo.com21yahoo.com that has another .com after yahoo.com